# siteSpeedSampleRate and cross domain tracking for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up cross domain tracking on my site and have siteSpeedSampleRate setup already in the 'create' piece of the code. After following Google's instructions to setup cross domain tracking there is no place where it says to place the siteSpeedSampleRate piece.

Here is what I have now:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain2.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Do I place the siteSpeedSampleRate piece on a new line like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', {'siteSpeedSampleRate':100});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain2.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Or is there a better way to do it?
I don't know what the 'create' line is for and can't find an answer that makes sense to me. If I use the 2nd piece of code on my site, when I look at Google's tag assistant it looks like it's firing twice.

Is there a way to implement both of these together?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "create" line creates a new tracker, and overwrites previous instances. So you do not want to call it twice - the second one would overwrite the first one with the configuration for cross domain tracking.

To pass in multiple configuration options you can use the configuration object. That's the last parameter in the create call (the bit in the curly brackets).

You can pass in key/value pairs to the configuration object, where the key must be valid field names. These are listed in the documentation as [create only fields](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create) (also the [userId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId) field might be set on create).

So your example should more look like:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto', {
   'allowLinker': true
   siteSpeedSampleRate':100
});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain2.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```